# Stripe works in localhost but gives error in live

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm currently developing a stripe checkout for my website, it's working in localhost but gives me this error : JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. In localhost I get this error if I name in a JSON payment intent field that does not exist, I've already set the live website in HTTPS channel

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post code so people are more easily able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has [a support article that explains how to debug and fix this error](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-to-fix-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0).